# Hyperledger Fabric: Native Binaries vs Docker Images

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

As far as I see from Hyperledger Fabric makefile, the compilation not only creates native binaries for peer and orderer but also creating docker images for peer and orderer. (peer vs peer-docker, orderer vs orderer-docker)

What is the purpose of having both native binary and docker image? Are these completing each other or just providing alternatives to each other?

Answer (score 0):

They provide alternatives to each other. You can use the Makefile to create only the native binaries (`make native`), or only the docker images (`make docker`).